# Program 'tsc' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Below is my devDependencies in package.json

```
"@types/jasmine": "^3.6.2",
"@types/node": "^14.14.19",
"jasmine": "^3.6.3",
"protractor": "^7.0.0",
"typescript": "^4.1.3"
```

When trying to run `node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc Sample.ts` I get the below error:

```
Program 'tsc' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation line:1 char:1
+ node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc Sample.ts
```

My system path variable

```
C:\Users\chinm\AppData\Roaming\npm 
C:\Users\chinm\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually there is a shebang line at top of file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

This specifies which program should run the script but Windows OS doesn't support shebang. So ideally you should not use this complete path for running `tsc`. Let the package manager handle this.

If you have installed tsc with npm use :

```
npx tsc Sample.ts
```

for yarn use :

```
yarn tsc Sample.ts
```